# Read json file in and write without indentation

Tags: json, file, rust, rust-cargo

The following code take a folder of json files (saved with indentation) open it, get content and serialize to json and write to file a new file.
Same code task in python works, so it is not the data. But the rust version you see in here:

```
extern crate rustc_serialize;
use rustc_serialize::json;
use std::io::Read;
use std::fs::read_dir;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Write;
use std::io;
use std::str;


fn write_data(filepath: &str, data: json::Json) -> io::Result<()> {

    let mut ofile = try!(File::create(filepath));
    let encoded: String = json::encode(&data).unwrap();
    try!(ofile.write(encoded.as_bytes()));
    Ok(())
}


fn main() {

    let root = "/Users/bling/github/data/".to_string();
    let folder_path = root + &"texts";
    let paths = read_dir(folder_path).unwrap();

    for path in paths {
        let input_filename = format!("{}", path.unwrap().path().display());
        let output_filename = str::replace(&input_filename, "texts", "texts2");

        let mut data = String::new();
        let mut f = File::open(input_filename).unwrap();
        f.read_to_string(&mut data).unwrap();
        let json = json::Json::from_str(&data).unwrap();

        write_data(&output_filename, json).unwrap();
    }
}
```

Do you have spot an Error in my code already or did I get some language concepts wrong. Is the rustc-serialize cargo wrongly used. At the end it does not work as expected - to outperform python.

```
± % cargo run --release --verbose                                                                                                                                            
       Fresh rustc-serialize v0.3.16
       Fresh fileprocessing v0.1.0 (file:///Users/bling/github/rust/fileprocessing)
     Running `target/release/fileprocessing`
thread '<main>' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: SyntaxError("unescaped control character in string", 759, 55)', ../src/libcore/result.rs:736
Process didn't exit successfully: `target/release/fileprocessing` (exit code: 101)
```

Why does it throw an error is my serializing json done wrong?
Can I get the object it fails on? What about encoding?

...is the code right or is there something obvious wrong with some more experience?

Comment: What are you asking? Are you asking why it's slower than Python ("*to outperform python*")? Are you asking why you are getting an error? *SyntaxError("unescaped control character in string", 759, 55)* — Have you looked at the file at that position to see why you have a control character? *it is not the data* — it's more than possible that one of Rust or Python is more strict about the JSON standard.

Comment: Sorry, was not as obvious as thought and added the question to the end now. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that one of your input files contains invalid JSON. You need to figure out which file (print the file name?) and then look at line 759, column 55 to figure out what it is. That's what the error message is telling you.

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess: if the same input file can be parsed by other JSON parsers (e.g. in Python), you may be hitting a rustc-serialize bug that was fixed in https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustc-serialize/pull/142. Try to update?